# Rewrite url rules in .htaccess inside a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use rewrite url rules using a .htaccess file. This seems to work fine in my main .htaccess file (only works for php pages which exist in same directory), but when I want to use another .htaccess for php file inside a subdirectory the rules don't apply at all and I get a 404 error page.

The file I want to point to is /news/story.php. story.php requests an integer variable called 'article' to fetch the article from database and display it.
So basically what I want to do is replace http://www.mydomain.com/news/story.php?article=1
with http://www.mydomain.com/news/story/article/1/

I'm using the following rules in the .htaccess file which is inside the 'news' directory.

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule story/article/(.*)/ story.php?article=$1
RewriteRule story/article/(.*) story.php?article=$1
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try something like `RewriteRule story/article/(.*) subFolder/page.php?article=$1` to access page.php placed in the folder subFolder. Of course the part immediately after RewriteRule is to be changed according to your needs.

Comment: I used what you suggested and it seems to work now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule story/article/(.*)/ news/story.php?article=$1
RewriteRule story/article/(.*) news/story.php?article=$1
```